# Can I pay in shops with the Google Pay website?

Tags: online-payment, contactless

Fairly self-explanatory: can I pay in a shop using the Google Pay website on my phone, rather than having the app?

Comment: Have you asked Google?

Comment: And it probably depends on the shop.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the seller. Generally you *can* use the Google Pay service as a money transfer service (similar to Venmo, PayPal, etc). But that is a completely different method of payment than using a credit card stored in the Google Pay app. Most stores showing the Google Pay/Apple Pay logos expect the former and would support any NFC-based card wallet app and not just Google or Apple.

Comment: Sorry, could've phrased my question a bit better -

Comment: I have my card stored on the Google wallet app on my phone. What i want to know is, if i log into the google pay website on another device (i can't get the app on that device), could I use the website to pay for things in a physical shop? Does the website work like the app?

Comment: @pythonbeginner no, it doesn't. The app uses the phone hardware that is not available through the web interface